# 'Module' Object Has no Attribute 'models' error in django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a simple blog engine. Here is my initial code for the models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Entry(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    author = models.models.models.ForeignKey(User)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()
```

When I try to run `python manage.py syncdb blog`, I get the error

```
'Module' Object Has no Attribute 'models'
```

I'm using sqlite3. I haven't set up any views or tests yet. In `settings.py`, I have included the following apps:

```
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blogApp',
'south',
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Have you named your project or any other files `django`?  You could have a name collision for the module name on the PYTHONPATH.  Also, is the error on the first or second import?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have

```
author = models.models.models.ForeignKey(User)
```

that should probably be

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

instead.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even notice that... of course a stack trace would have made it somewhat more obvious...

Comment: django swallows the stacktrace by default